# How to use regex in shell file (.sh) to capture '\' and newline (linefeed)?

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk

I am trying to capture '\' and newline in a shell file (.sh).
I've tried in the site: https://regexr.com/ and it works.
But it seems the way is not the same as in the shell file.

Here is the target and i wanna get those three **match groups**:

```
 some dummy code in front of
blablabla
 CE3( Match_Group_1, \(some space may right after this backslash)
      Match_Group_2, \(some space may right after this backslash)
      Match_Group_3,    \(some space may right after this backslash)
      abcabc1234,   \(some space may right after this backslash)
    abcd12345      )

blablabla
     blablabla
```

My regex in https://regexr.com/:
'\s*' can capture space, tab and newline. Get those match groups by (\w+)

```
 \s*\(\s*(\w+)\s*,\s*\\\s*(\w+)\s*,\s*\\\s*(\w+)
```

My regex in shell file for match then print: it failed to get those three match groups

```
 awk_cmd="awk 'match(\$0, /(${i})\\s*\(\\s*(\\w+)\\s*,\\s*\\\\s*(\\w+)\\s*,\\s*\\\\s*(\\w+)/, g) {print FILENAME \",\" NR \",\" g[1] \",\" g[3] \",\" g[4]}'"
```

Could anyone help me
So many thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO, thanks for sharing your efforts along with sample input and sample output, keep it up. Happy learning on this great site SO.

Comment: Beware trying to parse a structured language using Bash. If there is any parser library for this language you will be much happier in the long term using that than trying to use write-only regexes.

Comment: @Magneto5566, please add sample output too in your post.

Comment: Different tools use different variants of regex syntax. RegExr.com says it supports JavaScript & PHP/PCRE syntax, which has some significant differences from what awk uses. The most relevant difference is that awk doesn't support `\s` or `\w`. There's a reference for awk (and gawk) syntax [here](https://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/gawk_5.html).

Comment: Before trying to save your awk command in a shell variable and executing it from that, try top get it working on it's own first. Once you have that working - don't save your script in a variable, put it in an alias or function depending if it takes args or not.

Comment: @GordonDavisson though what you say is true in general, in this case the OP is using GNU awk which does support \s and \w.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about your question.  You say you want to use RE in a shell file, but which shell?  You tag `bash` but mention `sh` everywhere (file extensions are meaningless on UNIX-like systems).  `bash` has native REs, `sh` does not, yet you are using `awk`, so is your question about `sh`, `bash` or `awk`?  They are different languages and have different RE environments.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
$ awk_cmd() {
    awk -v RS='^$' -v OFS='","' '
        match($0,/\s*\(\s*(\w+)\s*,\s*\\\s*(\w+)\s*,\s*\\\s*(\w+)/,g) {
            print "\"" FILENAME, NR, g[1], g[2], g[3] "\""
        }
    ' "$@"
}

$ awk_cmd file
"file","1","Match_Group_1","Match_Group_2","Match_Group_3"

$ cat file | awk_cmd
"-","1","Match_Group_1","Match_Group_2","Match_Group_3"
```

Since your regexp has to span multiple lines it's not clear what value you expect NR to have. In the above I'm treating the whole input file as a single record so NR will always just be 1. If you're trying to print the line number where the string that matches the regexp starts that'd be:

```
$ awk_cmd() {
    awk -v RS='^$' -v OFS='","' '
        match($0,/(.*)\s*\(\s*(\w+)\s*,\s*\\\s*(\w+)\s*,\s*\\\s*(\w+)/,g) {
            nr = gsub(/\n/,"&",g[1]) + 1
            print "\"" FILENAME, nr, g[2], g[3], g[4] "\""
        }
    ' "$@"
}

$ awk_cmd file
"file","3","Match_Group_1","Match_Group_2","Match_Group_3"
```

The above uses GNU awk for multi-char RS and the 3rd arg to match() and `\s` and `\w` shorthand for `[[:space:]]` and `[[:alnum:]_]`.

Answer (score 0):

So this `awk` solution is relative more portable, since it *doesn't* require `gawk`'s custom extension within `match()` function -

- `match(s, r`  **`[, a]`** `)`

  — The optional array where `gawk` stores individual match groups on your behalf.

——————————————————————————————————————————————————

```
 ------------
| input   :: |
 ------------

 some dummy code in front of
blablabla
 CE3( Match_Group_1, \    $     # The dollar signs         <[ $  ]>
      Match_Group_2, \    $     # denote location of true 
      Match_Group_3,    \     $ # line ending in order to  
      abcabc1234,   \     $     # showcase trailing spaces 
    abcd12345      )            # after backslash          <[ \\ ]>
                                # but b4 actual newline    <[ \n ]>
blablabla
     blablabla
```

——————————————————————————————————————————————————

```
 ------------
| command :: |
 ------------

 [mg]awk '
 BEGIN {
     __ = sprintf("%.*s%.*s",!+(\
     RS = "^$" ), 
    OFS =   \
     (_ =   "\"")(",")(_),+_,
     FS = "[,]"(_="[ \t\v\f\r]*")"[\\\\]"(_)(\
     __ = "["(ORS)"]")(_)"|^.*"(__)(_)"[^(]+[(]"(_))
 }

 FNR < NR {      # This just to showcase it can handle 
                 # spaces, unicode, and emojis 
                 # inside the match group

     gsub("Match[_]Group[_]","Match Group \360\237\244\241 ")
 }

 $!NF=($(!(NF-=($!!—-NF= sprintf("%s%s:%.f%s%.f", __,
                                        FILENAME,
                                FNR,OFS,NR))^_))) __'
```

——————————————————————————————————————————————————

```
 ------------
| output  :: |
 ------------

"testbackslash_0002.txt:1","1","Match_Group_1","Match_Group_2","Match_Group_3"

"testbackslash_0001.txt:1","2","Match Group  1","Match Group  2","Match Group  3"

.
```